# Can someone show me how to style a radiobutton in Silverlight XAML to outline it (or change it's color) when it get's focus?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a radiobutton VisualStateGroup for Focuses, but I don't know how to change the storyboard to highlight the radiobutton on focus.

```
 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentFocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out.  It turns out the the target element needed to be layered on top of the other elements.